# take photo and to save in SD CARD or camera album PHONEGAP

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, storage, photos

I took this code that other participants mentioned and I tested it and it works fine, the only thing I want is to save the photo in a new folder that I create or even among album of photos from the camera to avoid having to go to the hidden path where currently is saved .. please help me

https://gist.github.com/2238017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a phonegap app, the picture i take with the camera are getting saved in the standard gallery folder on the phone.

Try my code :)

```
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,{
          quality : 25, 
          destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
          sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
          allowEdit : true,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          targetWidth: 500,
          targetHeight: 500,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: true });
}
```

Btw.. its the saveToPhotoAlbum: true that you are missing it looks like, anyways try my code out and i hope it works :)

Comment: thank you Daniel, I proved the code and saveToPhotoAlbum: true was what I was missing.

Comment: Great :)  Im happy to hear so.  :)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer so we can get the question closed :)